# Empty response body when parsing API with Retrofit and Gson

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I used Retrofit and Gson on this project. I'm trying to login where I should get a response of the user id, faunadb_token, and also data list filled with user data.

```
"body": "{\n    \"content\": {\n        \"id\": \"328803596056396364\",\n        \"faunadb_token\": \"fauna fnEEnk81KUACTwSP8HIOwApJqbjNg-u4fqC9q6Da2FvPTP2esYs\",\n        \"data\": {\n            \"name\": \"test2\",\n            \"email\": \"bowner@gmail.com\",\n            \"role\": \"admin\",\n            \"organization_id\": \"328992226856141394\",\n            \"address\": \"address local\",\n            \"birthdate\": \"2000-04-13\",\n            \"phonenumber\": \"0811033222\",\n            \"s3_image\": \"https://assignmentsystem.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/userimages/0abf8e6b-c2b2-4e49-9a88-10ffb3fffaba-272327.jpg\"\n        }\n    },\n    \"message\": \"Successful Login\",\n    \"errors\": []\n}"
```

However, when I'm logging in, I got a statusCode of 200, yet my response.body is all null. For testing purposes, I create a textview to see what the response is.

[image: Screenshot of response.body returns null]

But, in the terminal I can see that the actual response body is there, I just don't know how to get that(Third line from bottom).

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 https://api.absensia.online/backend/user/login (1111ms)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-powered-by: Express
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: access-control-allow-origin: *
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: etag: W/"1b0-6FklyrUjQI2dIrZLhEXcT1rvf1A"
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: vary: Accept-Encoding
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: date: Mon, 27 Jun 2022 07:45:02 GMT
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-kong-upstream-latency: 264
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: x-kong-proxy-latency: 1
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: via: kong/2.8.1
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"content":{"id":"328803596056396364","faunadb_token":"fauna fnEEqE4wt-ACUQSP8HIOwApJ7n1pLvPWUfBNciPtrEL0t1ifoT8","data":{"name":"test2","email":"bowner@gmail.com","role":"admin","organization_id":"328992226856141394","address":"address local","birthdate":"2000-04-13","phonenumber":"0811033222","s3_image":"https://assignmentsystem.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/userimages/default.png"}},"message":"Successful Login","errors":[]}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (432-byte body)
D/EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=16.10ms min=1.92ms max=565.09ms count=42
```

Here are some of my code:

ApiConfig

```
object ApiConfig {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://api.absensia.online/backend/"
    private val client: Retrofit
        get() {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build()
        }

    val instanceRetrofit: ApiService
        get() = client.create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

ApiService

```
interface ApiService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("user/login")
    suspend fun login(
        @Field("email") email:String,
        @Field("password") password:String,
    ): Response<LoginResponse>

    @GET("user/logout")
    suspend fun logout(
        @Header("Auth") auth: String
    ): Response<ResponseAuth>

}
```

LoginResponse class

```
data class LoginResponse(

    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: String?,

    @SerializedName("faunadb_token")
    var faunadb_token: String?,

    @SerializedName("data")
    var data: User?
)
```

Repository

```
class Repository {

    suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Response<LoginResponse>{
        return ApiConfig.instanceRetrofit.login(email, password)
    }

    suspend fun logout(auth: String): Response<ResponseAuth>{
        return ApiConfig.instanceRetrofit.logout(auth)
    }
}
```

AuthenticationViewModel

```
class AuthenticationViewModel(private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {

    var loginResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<LoginResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    var logout: MutableLiveData<Response<ResponseAuth>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun login(email: String, password: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = repository.login(email, password)
            loginResponse.value = response
        }
    }

    fun logout(auth: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = repository.logout(auth)
            logout.value = response
        }
    }

}
```

AuthenticationViewModelFactory

```
class AuthenticationViewModelFactory(private val repository: Repository): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return AuthenticationViewModel(repository) as T
    }

}
```

LoginActivity

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var loginpref: SharedPref
    private lateinit var viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_masuk)
        loginpref = SharedPref(this)

        val masuk = findViewById<Button>(R.id.masuk_btn)
        masuk.setOnClickListener {
            masukButton()
        }

        buttonsMasukTest()
    }

    private fun masukButton(){
        val masukEmail = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.masukHpEmail)
        val masukPass = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.masukPass)

        val masukEmailLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.masukHpEmail_layout)
        val masukPassLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.masukPass_layout)

        val loadMasuk = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.load_masuk)

        masukEmailLayout.isErrorEnabled = false
        masukPassLayout.isErrorEnabled = false

        if (masukEmail.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            masukEmailLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
            masukEmailLayout.error = "Mohon mengisi kolom ini"
            masukEmailLayout.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (masukPass.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            masukPassLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
            masukPassLayout.error = "Mohon mengisi kolom ini"
            masukPassLayout.requestFocus()
            return
        }
        if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(masukEmail.text.toString()).matches()){
                masukEmailLayout.isErrorEnabled = true
                masukEmailLayout.error = "Mohon mengisi email dengan benar"
                masukEmailLayout.requestFocus()
                return
        }

        loadMasuk.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        val repository = Repository()
        val viewModelFactory = AuthenticationViewModelFactory(repository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AuthenticationViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.login(
            masukEmail.text.toString(),
            masukPass.text.toString())
        viewModel.loginResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                loadMasuk.visibility = View.GONE

                val respon = response.body()

                loginpref.setStatusLogin(true)

                respon?.data?.let { loginpref.setUser(it) }
                respon?.faunadb_token?.let { loginpref.saveToken(it) }

                /**
                 * Momentary textview so I can know my respon
                 */
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.testing).setText(respon.toString())

                /**
                 * I comment the section where it start the next activity for testing purposes
                 */
//                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
//                startActivity(intent)
//                finish()
//                Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Welcome " + masukEmail.text.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            }else if(!response.isSuccessful){
                loadMasuk.visibility = View.GONE
                Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "Login failed: Your Email or Password is Incorrect : "+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })

    }

    private fun buttonsMasukTest(){
        val testMasuk = findViewById<Button>(R.id.masuk_btnTest)

        testMasuk.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent (this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            loginpref.setStatusLogin(true)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new with Kotlin, I tried to read and watch from several sources regarding Okhttp, retrofit, gson, and viewmodel but with no avail in solving the issue. Any help and advice would be appreciated regarding how I can get the response body. Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to annotate each field both of `LoginResponse` and `User` with `@SerializedName("response_field_name")`. E.g. `data class LoginResponse(@SerializedName("id") var id: String?, @SerializedName("faunadb_token") var faunadb_token: String?, @SerializedName("data") var data: User?)`.

Comment: I tried to put all the @SerializedName but my response is still null

Comment: The response body has `content` object that has to be a "wrapper" class for `LoginResponse`.

Comment: Sorry Onik I dont understand what you mean, so is it that I need to have a function to unwrapped the content object inside the response? If so, why does the content object not shown when I print the response.body()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("user/login")
suspend fun login(
    @Field("email") email:String,
    @Field("password") password:String,
): Response<ContentResponse>



data class ContentResponse(
     @SerializedName("content")
     val loginResponse: LoginResponse
)
```

Maybe this can help you. you are getting data in content node so

Comment: Thank you Ankita, this does solved the issue. I didn't know I need to create another data class, I thought I can just directly access what inside the content is directly.